# Ghost effect using Open GLES

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glkit, glkview

I am working with a sample application like vine. My requirement is that I have to create a 'ghost' filter for video as in vine.

Actual requirement is

-Record a video on long press on the view

-On pause of record, I need to show the last frame of the recorded video above my view. Please see the expected working [here](http://andrewmacarthy.com/andrew-macarthy-social-media/how-to-use-vine-apps-ghost-mode-ghosting-on-vine-tips)

I have checked [PBJVision](https://github.com/piemonte/PBJVision) library and found this feature working. But I need to implement this feature separately in my application.

While analysing the code, I found that this can be achieved using Open GLES. I have tried using a GLKView but it just shows a dark shade instead of image frame. Since I am new in this area, please help me.

Comment: What does a "ghost" filter do? (I clicked on the link and it's just a bunch of code - no description at all.) What part are you stuck on? Show us the code you've written so far and where you're having trouble.

Comment: Some more edit is made in the question. Please have a look and help me

Comment: Fixed this issue without Open GLES. The solution written was to load recorded video using 'AVAssetImageGenerator' and create the 'CGImageRef' of the last point of video. This time can be gotten using 'asset.duration'.